# Cannot get proxy to work on bluestacks using command line

Tags: proxy, bluestacks

I am having a lot of problems getting this to work. [I am following this tutorial](https://www.51sec.org/2020/11/21/tips-and-tricks-to-run-android-emulator-bluestacks/).

[Some sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24904945/command-prompt-error-c-program-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-c) say you need to put quotes in the command line.

Here is what the command looks like. I set cmd.exe to run with admin privileges.  I cannot get it to work with quotes or without:

[image: Command Line - Screenshot]

Here is what the file manager looks like:

[image: File Manager - Screenshot]

The program exists and is running but I cannot get it to work via the command line.

I am using Windows 11 and bluestacks version 5.

Also, I have the proxy server I want to use. So can this be done with a single line command with the proxy server?

Comment: Cross-posted from Super User: https://superuser.com/q/1699457/356789.

Comment: Please try the answer in the linked duplicate question.